MSAL logout after a while and can't get new session on sltn token acquires
The application uses WebView as a SPA (Single page app) to display the web application in the Android application and MSAL for user authorization and access to the application. After the sign-in prompt, the user logs in normally and can view the web view with data. We see that token expires in 2h and it works fine to acquire silent token in next 24h, but after that even get new token web view does not work. However, the next day it is no longer possible and the app redirects the user back to the sign-in prompt (but we want to avoid logging in every day) because it seems as if the token or session has expired. And there is also a silent get token that will eventually be renewed, but I don't know what to do with that token (how can I put it in the cache so that it can be used) because we don't send the token in the header for that webview, but it seems to me that after logging in, the server establishes a session and cookies with the webview and thus has access as long as the session/token is active. Now I don't understand how to solve that problem and whether that webview somehow connects to that session after the sign-in process. I would appreciate it if anyone has the experience to share. I also read the cookies, but I don't see any token in them.
